# Access variables from viewdidLoad() inside a class function

Tags: ios, swift

i try to access the variable "viewControllers" from the two class functions, but i always get the errors on the picture.

[image]

How can i solve the issue to access the variable from viewDidLoad() to switch with Tabman between the two ContainerViews?

Comment: Do not show pictures of code.

Comment: for other hand: *WhatContainerView* and *WhereContainerView* must be UIViewControllers

Comment: Declare viewControllers array out side(top of ur IBOutlet variables) of viewDidLoad method, then you can access out side. Right now viewControllers variable is local you can not access out side of method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `var viewController` declaration is inside the curly braces of the `viewDidLoad` function, so it is temporary and invisible to other code.

Move the `var viewController` declaration up a level so that it becomes an instance property that your other methods can see.

Comment: See my http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime to learn about _scope_ in Swift.

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry to show a screenshot as code. When i move the variable viewControllers outside the viewDidLoad function, i get the following issue: "Cannot use instance member 'WhatContainerView' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: Yup, you'd need to make this a `lazy var`. Again, see my http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_lazy_initialization.

Comment: thanks matt - that was the solution, but i get another error... please the the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17EQfDDWEqnvODLFmIKUFwajknO911RF9/view?usp=sharing) I use Container View, because i don't need a full height and with UIViewController - [see this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18aMHcpedwdbYvhgYQxA2DACvuTH-CfRz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I answered _the question you asked_. Turning it into another question and continuing to pick my brains in the comments is called "leeching" or "churning". Besides, if you wanted an array of view _controllers_ it was pretty silly to make an array of _views_ to begin with, wasn't it?

Comment: "sorry to show a screenshot as code" You're still doing it, though.

Comment: i have opened a new question(51993461). Sorry for the linking pictures, but i don‘t know a better way to show you my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise a variable in class scope. Something like that.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

  var viewControllers = [controller1, controller2]

  // your code

}
```

It's off topic, but I promise to share a code example how to create a TabBarController programmatically.

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViewControllers()
    }

    private func setupViewControllers() {
        //1st viewController
        let firstViewController = UIViewController()
        firstViewController.view.backgroundColor = .green

        let firstNavController = templateNavController(unselectedImage: UIImage(named: "yourImage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "yourImageSelected"), roootViewController: firstViewController)

        //2nd 
        let secondViewController = UIViewController()
        secondViewController.view.backgroundColor = .red

        let secondNavController = templateNavController(unselectedImage: UIImage(named: "yourSecondImage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "yourSecondImageSelected"), roootViewController: secondNavController)

        // put your controllers here
        viewControllers = [firstNavController, secondNavController]
    }


    private func templateNavController(unselectedImage: UIImage, selectedImage: UIImage, roootViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()) -> UINavigationController {
        let viewController = roootViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navController.tabBarItem.image = unselectedImage
        navController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage
        return navController
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry to show a screenshot as code. When i move the variable viewControllers outside the viewDidLoad function, i get the following issue: "Cannot use instance member 'WhatContainerView' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: the problem is that you want to add two UIViews which has connected to your TabViewController. Your WhatContainerView and WhereContainerView can't be UIViewControllers.
You should initialise your view controllers. Ok I'll write code example, just edit my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

scope of any variables in any programming language local or global

local are those variables declared with in a function and global variables are those variables declared at class level.

you are declaring your variable inside the function which means the access of these variables are limited to with in a function.

Declare your variables at class level. Here's the code -

```
class TableviewController:UIViewController
{
var whatContentView:UIView!
var whereContentView:UIView!
var viewControllers:[UIView] = [whatContentView,whereContentView]

// your code

}
```